# Debugging a request/response in Python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to [python2 flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) & I am tasked to pretty print & save the entire HTTP request and response to file. I don't quite understand how to print/inspect the request object, let alone the response.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hi():
    print (request)
    return 'oh hai'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any tips? Each request/response should be one file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using [**after_request**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request)

```python
@app.after_request
def after(response):
    # todo with response
    print(response.status)
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.get_data())
    return response
```

Also, to deal with request with [**before_request**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)

```
@app.before_request
def before():
    # todo with request
    # e.g. print request.headers
    pass
```

### Edit:

`response.get_data()` can get the data of response. And `response` is the whole object for response. It can fetch anything you want.

### Update for some specific url (based on http://s.natalian.org/2016-03-19/foo.py):

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from flask import Flask, request, g
    import time
    app = Flask(__name__)             

    @app.route('/')
    def hi():
        g.fn = str(time.time()) + ".txt"
        with open(g.fn,'w') as f:
            print ("Request headers", request.headers, file=f)            
        return 'oh hai'

    @app.route('/foo')
    def foo():
        return 'foo'

    @app.before_request
    def before():
        pass

    @app.after_request
    def after(response):
        fn = g.get('fn', None)
        if fn:
            with open(fn, 'a') as f:
                print("Printing response", file=f)
                print(response.status, file=f)
                print(response.headers, file=f)
                print(response.get_data(), file=f)
        return response

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: How do I see the entire raw response?

Comment: @hendry edit for you

Comment: How do I track the request and response? For example I want the request to get an epoch timestamp.txt and response to be stored to be stored in the same file. New requests are separate files. This as far as I got http://s.natalian.org/2016-03-19/foo.py

Comment: @hendry you can use `g` (from flask import g), it is a global object for thread.

Comment: Could you please update your example? Also I am not clear how one attaches to just one route, not the entire app. Maybe there is a debugging option I missed?

Comment: @hendry updated for you

Comment: This does not work properly for me because of connexion_swagger. This solution unfortunately captures any connexion_swagger ui requests and responses and will print those out too. Annoying as that is, it also breaks swagger as responses to the UI get redirected here first and none of the files are returned to the web interface.